# How to add alert message to a global class

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code repeated in many of my `view controllers`. I would like to refactor it into a global class/view controller. However, I still want it to be shown with the parent as the current view controller so that when I click OK it will return to the current view controller where the error occurred. What should the name of that global class be and should it subclass `UIViewController`?

```
    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: - Alert Error Message
    //--------------------------------------
    func displayAlertMessage(title:String,message:String)
    {
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .default, handler:nil);

        alertMessage.addAction(okAction);

        self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
```

Comment: Why not write it as an extension to `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `UIViewController` extension and implement this method there. This will allow you to call it from any `UIViewController` subclass.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func displayAlertMessage(title: String, message: String)
    {
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .default, handler:nil);

        alertMessage.addAction(okAction);

        self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}
```

You could also add a `handler` and `completion` parameters to the `displayAlertMessage` function, which would allow you to customize the both the action handler and what happens when the alert finishes being presented, from the calling point.

Answer (score 2):

I like extensions for this.

If you extend uiviewcontroller you should be able to put this function inside and then you'd be able to call it from any view controller.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.0**

You can use action closure for multiple actions.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func popupAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actionTitles:[String?], actions:[((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?]) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        for (index, title) in actionTitles.enumerated() {
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default, handler: actions[index])
            alert.addAction(action)
        }
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And you can use like this in UIViewController

```
 popupAlert(title: kTitle, message: "This is test alert!!!!" , actionTitles: ["Ok","Cancel"], actions: [ { action1 in
            //perform action for OK button
            }, { action2 in
           //perform action for cancel button
  }])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its just simple Just create a new NSObject class and Do the following**

```
class WrapperClass: NSObject 
{    
    class func BasicAlert(_ title : String, message : String, view:UIViewController)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title:title, message:  message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
WrapperClass.BasicAlert("Error", message: "Bluetooth Headset is Not Connected, Please Retry", view: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SCLAlertView](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift) for simple alert creation. The alert is always shown from the current view controller and returns to this controller when the alert is closed. This static function shows a simple message with an OK button. Of course, you can also add text fields, buttons and other elements. These alerts are especially nice because you can call them at any point in your code, even from background queues.

```
class Alerts {

    static func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = SCLAlertView()
            alert.showCustom(title, subTitle: message, color: UIColor.blue, icon: UIImage(named: "logo")!, closeButtonTitle: "OK")
        }
    }

}
```